# CacheLoader loading the same keys in multiple times

Tags: java, web-services, caching, soap

I am getting duplicate keys in my cacheIterator.

I'm calling a web service using SOAP to rate policies for an insurance company. I am attempting to use a Cachebuilder / loader to store the DTO's as a key and the response from the service as a value. From what I've researched, the .get and .getUnchecked methods will get a value from the cache and if it's not there, it will load that value into the cache. 
here is some code:

```
public class CacheLoaderImpl
{
   private static CacheLoaderImpl instance = null;
   private static LoadingCache<PolicyDTO, RatingServiceObjectsResponse> responses;

   protected CacheLoaderImpl()
   {
      responses = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build(
                new CacheLoader<PolicyDTO, RatingServiceObjectsResponse>() {
                  public RatingServiceObjectsResponse load(PolicyDTO key)
                        throws Exception
                  {
                      return getResponse(key);
                  }
                });
   }

   public static CacheLoaderImpl getIntance()
   {
      if(instance == null)
      {
         instance = new CacheLoaderImpl();
      }

      return instance;
   }

   public LoadingCache<PolicyDTO, RatingServiceObjectsResponse> getResponses()
   {
      return responses;
   }

   public RatingServiceObjectsResponse getResponse(PolicyDTO key) throws ExecutionException
   {
     RatingServiceObjectsResponse response = new RatingServiceObjectsResponse();
     try
     {
         response = new CGIRatabaseServiceImpl().getCoverages(key);
     }
     catch (RemoteException e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return response;

   }

}
```

And this is where I call the get method:

```
RatingServiceObjectsResponse response = CacheLoaderImpl.getIntance().getResponses().get(policy.toCoveragesCallDTO());
```

I was under the assumption that maybe it was comparing memory addresses which would be different so I overwrote the toString method to convert the DTO object to JSON. Upon inspecting the cache I can see that the keys are exactly the same with a compare tool. Yet, they're still being stored and calling the service every single time. I tried overwriting the equals method on PolicyDTO but it is never hit when I debug.

How can I make the cacheloader only load values of different keys and pull existing values out as it is originally intended?

I think I just don't have a solid idea how the cacheLoader actually works. I appreciate any help or suggestions.

PolicyDTO class:

```
public class PolicyDTO extends AbstractDto implements IPolicyDTO
{
   private ArrayList<ILineOfBusinessDTO> lobDTOs = new ArrayList<ILineOfBusinessDTO>();
   private String pcInd;
   private String ratingEffectiveDate;
   private String companyName;

   public String getPcInd()
   {
      return pcInd;
   }

   public void setPcInd(String pcInd)
   {
      this.pcInd = pcInd;
   }

   public String getRatingEffectiveDate()
   {
      return ratingEffectiveDate;
   }

   public void setRatingEffectiveDate(AdvancedDate ratingEffectiveDate)
   {
      if(ratingEffectiveDate != null)
      {
         this.ratingEffectiveDate = ratingEffectiveDate.toFormattedStringMMDDYYYY();
      }
      else
      {
         this.ratingEffectiveDate = new AdvancedDate().toFormattedStringMMDDYYYY();
      }
   }

   public String getCompanyName()
   {
      return companyName;
   }

   public void setCompanyName(String companyName)
   {
      this.companyName = companyName;
   }

  public DtoType getType()
   {
       return hasGetCoveragesCoverageDTO() ? DtoType.GET_COVERAGE_POLICY : DtoType.RATE_POLICY;
   }

   public boolean hasGetCoveragesCoverageDTO()
   {
       if(lobDTOs != null)
       {
           for(ILineOfBusinessDTO lineDTO : lobDTOs)
           {
               if(lineDTO.hasGetCoveragesCoverageDTO())
               {
                   return true;
               }
           }
       }

       return false;
   }

    @Override
    public void addLob(ILineOfBusinessDTO lob) {

        lobDTOs.add(lob);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<ILineOfBusinessDTO> getLobIterator() {

        return lobDTOs.iterator();
    }

    public ICoverageDTO findCoverage(String coverageID)
    {
        ICoverageDTO coverageDTO = null;

        for(ILineOfBusinessDTO lineDTO : lobDTOs)
        {
            coverageDTO = lineDTO.findCoverage(coverageID);

            if(coverageDTO != null)
            {
                return coverageDTO;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
       return JSONConversionUtility.convertPolicyDTO(this);
    }

    @Override
   public int hashCode()
   {
      final int prime = 31;
      int result = 1;
      result = prime * result
            + ((companyName == null) ? 0 : companyName.hashCode());
      result = prime * result + ((lobDTOs == null) ? 0 : lobDTOs.hashCode());
      result = prime * result + ((pcInd == null) ? 0 : pcInd.hashCode());
      result = prime
            * result
            + ((ratingEffectiveDate == null) ? 0 : ratingEffectiveDate
                  .hashCode());
      return result;
   }

    @Override 
   public boolean equals(Object object)
   {
      if(object instanceof PolicyDTO)
      {
         return object.toString().equals(this.toString());
      }
      return false;

   }
}
```

Comment: Can you share code for - 1. How and where you put stuff in cacheLoader and 2. PolicyDTO class

Comment: Did you override the `equals` **and** `hashCode` methods?

Comment: Ben Manes - Yes, but upon debugging I found it never gets into either method, only my toString override.

Comment: Raman: Thank you for your response. I posted the code for the PolicyDTO. Additionally, values are loaded into the cache upon calling the .get method. Behind the scenes it will attempt to get the value and, if it cannot be found, it will place the value into the cache. This is code built into the CacheLoader framework that I do not have access to.

Comment: You have at least two issues in your code that may or may not affect you. First, `CacheLoaderImpl.getIntance()` method should be synchronized or otherwise ensure only one-time instantiation. Second, `CacheLoaderImpl.responses` field should not be static.

Comment: Ah I didn't catch that. getInstance() is only called once but I did make the necessary changes you suggested. This will help me down the road. However, this doesn't fix my current issue. I did a file compare of the JSON strings inside the cache (keys) and they are identical. Is it possible that the CacheLoader is comparing the values before putting them into the cache instead of the keys?

Comment: When those two `PolicyDTO`s are `equal`, are their `hashCode`s equal too?

Comment: If you change `PolicyDTO.hashCode` implementation to just `return toString().hashCode()`, does it solve the problem?

Comment: Yes it did! Do you think this is an efficient way to compare the objects though?

Comment: No, I don't think that comparing string representations is efficient. You can directly compare the fields that contribute to `toString()` - that should be more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `PolicyDTO` class has `hashCode` inconsistent with `equals` - it violates the following rule:

> If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then
>   calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce
>   the same integer result.

Cache uses `hashCode` (much like `HashMap` class does), so when it sees two keys with different hashcodes, it assumes they are not equal.